# Pricing FRA rates from changes in rates due to ECB meetings and vice versa

Tags: optimization, forward-rate, forward-curve

This is somewhat building on top of my last question:
[Explicit step by step curve construction using FRAs](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/explicit-step-by-step-curve-construction-using-fras)

I'm trying build (in python) and understand something that will allow me to reprice 6M EURIBOR FRAs given changes decided (or presumed changes) on ECB meeting dates and vice-versa i.e. given the FRA rates what will be the optimised changes on the ECB meeting dates that will reproduce those rates.

My understanding of the procedure is as follows:

Changes in ECB meeting dates ---> Pricing FRAs

1. One is given a list of ECB dates and potential changes (measured in bps) on those dates (how changes are determined are not yet important for my understanding):

```
meeting_dates = [
    dt.date(2024, 3, 7),
    dt.date(2024, 4, 11),
    dt.date(2024, 6, 6),
    dt.date(2024, 7, 18),
    dt.date(2024, 9, 12),
    dt.date(2024, 10, 17),
    dt.date(2024, 12, 12),
]
turns = [-1, -7.5, -19.8, -16.7, -20, -18.2, -23.2]
```

2. The effect of this is there is a change in the O/N rate on the fixing dates (for simplicity im just gonna assume they are the same as the meeting dates)
3. This in turn affects the forward curve.
4. Using this new forward curve we can price FRAs

For this part my questions are:

1. Whether the procedure is correct?
2. I read JHM Darbyshire's book on IRDs and I thought the solution is to implement the changes on those dates as turns. So after building the curve, I then add turns and have another curve with new nodes. For simplicity I chose the nodes to be the meeting dates. I can now calculate forward rates between dates given this new curve. Question is how can I confirm this independently given the same changes on the meeting dates? I understand given those changes and one was to apply an analogous method to price futures then is would I expect the futures rate and the FRA rate (for the same accrual period as the futures) be the same?

Priced FRAs ----> Changes in ECB meeting dates

Im not really sure how to implement this. In principle I understand I am trying to calculate what is the optimal values for the changes on those dates those priced FRAs.

I am also trying to find an external measure to validate my results.

If someone can show an explicit formulation of each part then that would be great!